# Java/Android: Append multiple strings, skip if string is null

Tags: java, android, string, null, append

I have four strings I need to append.

```
String food = extras.getString("food");
String file = extras.getString("file");
String parcel = extras.getString("parcel");
String others = extras.getString("others");

String itemList = new StringBuilder(food).append("\n")
                      .append(file).append("\n")
                      .append(parcel).append("\n")
                      .append(others).toString();
```

This code will `prints`, if I choose `Food` and `File`.

```
Food
File
null
null
```

Since `Parcel` and Others have no values (which is `null`), how to make it will print like below?

```
Food
File
```

I tried to use `if else` but it will be too long (14 possibilities). Is there any other way to make it shorter and effective?

Comment: what is the type of `extras`

Comment: @PavneetSingh it's a bundle

Comment: what is the minimum API level you are supporting ? are you able to to use something like this `String food = extras.getString("food","");`

Comment: @PavneetSingh min API 16 and yes, it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8's streaming capabilities offer a pretty neat way of doing this:

```
String itemList =
    Stream.of(food, file, parcel, others)
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

EDIT:
For older versions of java, you could do something similar with a traditional `for` loop, although it would be clunkier:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : Arrays.asList(food, file, parcel, others)) {
    if (s != null) {
        sb.append(s).append('\n');
    }
}
String itemList = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol `Stream`.. I guess it's because of Java 8? But in Project Setting, already set jdk1.8.0_101

Comment: @August yup, probably. I'd highly recommend upgrading your JDK/Android version to a version that supports Streams. If this isn't possible, see my edited answer for a variant for older versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace all `null` values

```
    String food = "food";
    String file = "file";
    String parcel = null;
    String others = null;

    String itemList = new StringBuilder(food).append("\n").append(file).append("\n").append(parcel).append("\n").append(others).toString();
    itemList=itemList.replaceAll("\n?null\n?", "");
    System.out.println(itemList);
```

Output :

```
food
file
```

`\n?null\n?` `\n?` mean there can be one or no `\n` value on both side of `null`

so it will simply replace all values with empty string

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go for below Java 8 then its possible through Ternary Operator in java. Please see below code snippet:

```
String itemList = new StringBuilder(food!=null?food+"\n":"")
            .append(file!=null?file+"\n":"")
            .append(parcel!=null?parcel+"\n":"")
            .append(others!=null?others+"\n":"")
            .toString();
```

The `itemList` will have the desired result.
Hope it helps.